# Grouping pytest markers

Tags: python, pytest

If I have pytest markers that mark tests that require special treatment. For example, if they are too slow or special hardware is required, special OS, etc.

```
@pytest.mark.foo
def test_foo_1():
    # ...

@pytest.mark.bar
def test_bar_1():
    # ...
```

Then I can invoke tests that don't have these markers via `pytest -m "not foo and not bar"`.

Now If I have a lot of markers like that it can be annoying to type `pytest -m 'not foo and not bar and not zebra and not ...'` every time.

Is there a way to group all these special tests somehow such that I can run tests via `python -m 'not special'`? Except by adding another marker `special` to all of the special tests.

Comment: you can test the foo like  `python -m foo`  this will only test foo not bar

Comment: @prashantrana testing foo and bar individually is not a problem, problem is the opposite - how to simplify testing of everything except foo and bar.

Comment: @DikobrAz What's the problem with the verbose command line argument? You can just create another (Python / Bash) script to fill in the values and then invoke via `pytest -m "$(python create.py)"`.

Comment: @a_guest that's possible. Making convenience bash scripts is another option. I was just wondering if pytest provides some functionality to group markers together that I'm not aware about.

Comment: @DikobrAz try this [Marking whole classes or modules](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html#adding-a-custom-marker-from-a-plugin) this is solution i suppose.

Comment: @DikobrAz Alternatively you can use [substring matching](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html#using-k-expr-to-select-tests-based-on-their-name) or [conditional markers](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html#custom-marker-and-command-line-option-to-control-test-runs) (based on command line specification).

Comment: Thanks! These are good suggestions.

Comment: @DikobrAz don't forgot to post solution. :)